# Passing a relative file path through aws cloudformation deploy parameter-overrides

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am working on adding Dynatrace monitoring as a layer to a Lambda serverless function in a nested stack.  The environment variables needed for the Dynatrace layer are being passed from the root stack to the serverless function stack where they are received in a `Globals` block.

One of the needed environment variables is `AWS_LAMBDA_EXEC_WRAPPER`, and I am trying to pass a relative path of `/opt/dynatrace`.

I am developing and testing using bash shell scripts on my workstation, so I am using a script to execute the `aws cloudformation deploy` command and passing parameter overrides for the Dynatrace monitoring.  The variable in question is using `pDtLambdaExecWrapper=/opt/dynatrace`.

When passing the value as `/opt/dynatrace`, the path is being parsed as `C:/Program Files/Git/opt/dynatrace`, so gives an error that it does not exist.

I tried passing the value as `./opt/dynatrace`, but instead get an error, `./opt/dynatrace: does not exist`.

I am using a Windows 10 workstation, and using Git Bash for my terminal shell emulator.

Is there a way to pass in a relative file path from the AWS command line using the `parameter-overrides` option on the `aws cloudformation deploy` command in a way that will pass just `/opt/dynatrace`?

Deploy command below.  I've removed or changed some of the other parameters being passed in to save space.

```
aws --region $REGION cloudformation deploy \
--template-file $OUTPUT_TEMPLATE_FILE \
--stack-name $STACK_NAME \
--no-fail-on-empty-changeset \
--capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND \
--parameter-overrides \
pDtTenant=26571e7e-xxxx-4fed-a826-67b899abfee8 \
pDtClusterId=-nnnnnnnnnn \
pDtLambdaExecWrapper=/opt/dynatrace \
pDtLambdaLayerArn=arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxx:1
```

Comment: Did you try using double-quotes around the path? Then it'll be passed as a string.

Comment: I tried using both double and single quotes, with and without a dot (`./opt/dynatrace/`).  Same issues as before.

Comment: Can you update the question with the full command you're using?

Comment: Updated.  Thanks for taking a look at this.

Comment: I tried something similar and it works. Can you explain where you get the error when using "" and without them? It could be how you're using the parameter.

Comment: The error occurs in the CloudWatch log for the Lambda function when it is triggered.

Comment: Then your path is not available in the lambda function! Are you putting anything inside `/opt/dynatrace` ? You need to put your dynatrace libs there. Did you add DynaTrace as a Layer?
Check here: https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/technology-support/cloud-platforms/amazon-web-services/integrations/deploy-oneagent-as-lambda-extension/

Comment: The DynaTrace One Agent is being added as a layer to the lambda function.  The ARN for it is being passed as a parameter to my deploy script, and the Lambda console shows the layer, but I will double check on that.

Comment: Then I recommend programmatically scan the directories and see if the files are properly added from the layer.